# I'm looking for an Oracle Express Edition 11g testing database

Tags: data-request, sql

I am looking for a testing database that contains random tables full of random data where I can do my test. I just began studying Oracle express edition 11g, I am using Oracle SQL developer under Windows 7. I would like to have database's entity relation ship diagram so it would be easy for me to know table's attributes key...

Comment: Do you actually mean random data? Or do you mean that you are indifferent to the context of the data?

Comment: Im not intrested in the context, all im looking for is a big database. i want to try queries on it thats all I want.

Comment: related : http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/449/51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9534136/2327328), I found the page:

[**Creating the Sample Database in Oracle 11g Release 2**](http://www.fehily.com/books/createdb/createdb_oracle_11g_2.html) ([Other instructions](http://expectus.hubpages.com/hub/Newbie-Guide-to-Oracle-11g-Database-Common-Problems))

[image]

Also, if you are using XE, there is a [demo DB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18147/tdddg_connecting.htm#TDDDG99998) ready to play with.